# Command substitution and double quotes: why results are different?

Tags: bash, shell, command-substitution

Here is an example where backticks and $() behave differently:

```bsh
$ echo "$(echo \"test\")"
"test"
$ echo "`echo \"test\"`"
test
```

My understanding was this is because ["backslashes (\) inside backticks are handled in a non-obvious manner"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)

But it seems like this is something else because when I remove outer double quotes the results became similar:

```bsh
$ echo $(echo \"test\")
"test"
$ echo `echo \"test\"`
"test"
```

Could someone explain me how it works and why "`echo \"test\"`" removes double quotes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right, it is something else in this case.

The solution is still in [the same link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082), but the second point:

> - Nested quoting inside $() is far more convenient.
>
>   [...]
>
>   `...` requires backslashes around the internal quotes in order to be portable.

Thus,

```
echo "`echo \"test\"`"
```

does not equal this:

```
echo "$(echo \"test\")"
```

but this:

```
echo "$(echo "test")"
```

---

You need to compare it instead with this:

```
echo "`echo \\"test\\"`"
```

Comment: even better when nesting multiple times: at each "level" of $(... this level here...) you can write as if you were at the first level (the calling shell level). ex: `echo "this is $(echo "rater $(echo "silly")")"`

Comment: Your answer mentions observations but it does not explain **why** this different behavior can be observed.

Comment: The correct reason is that when a shell finds a `"` it starts a `Quoted scope`, that defines some parsing rules. When what is found is a (``` ` ```), the rules are quite different.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the command substitution with backticks removes the
quoting is caused by the way it is implemented:

- The text within the backticks is passed through the lexical parser a second time before it is finally executed.

  This happens because the results from passing the lexical parser a first time (that eats up one quoting level) is kept as a string and fed through the complete parser again during the final execution. So as a result backtick based command substitution removes two levels of quoting.
- The text within`$(...)` is kept unchanged before it is fed through the complete parser during the final execution.

  - this is implemented in `ksh` by recording the **input text** as a side efect of the parser while it is parsing for the closing `')̈́'` that matches the `$(`.
  - this is implemented in `bosh` and `mksh` by recording the binary syntax tree output from the parser while it is parsing for the closing `')̈́'` that matches the `$(` and reconstructing the related equivalent **original input** for that binary tree for the final execution.

  As a result, `$(...)` based command substitution removes only a single quoting level (as it happens for normal command execution as well).

Because of this implementation, backtick based command substitution causes unexpected behavior in special if `grep` patterns are part of such a command. This is why `$(...)` is recommended to be used in favor.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is what happens to a (double) quoted string.

As soon as the shell parser finds an (unquoted) `"` it declares the whole string that ends on the next (unquoted) `"` as quoted. Inside quoted strings, **most** backslashes **don't** get removed. In UN-quoted strings backslashes are removed.

From [POSIX (remove most backslashes)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_01):

> A `<backslash>` that is not quoted shall preserve the literal value of the following character, …

This will show that in practice (set -x show what the shell executes after parsing):

```
$ ksh -c 'set -x; echo test\h\jtest; set +x'
+ echo testhjtest
testhjtest
```

unquoted backslashes get removed. But quoted ones don't :

```
$ ksh -c 'set -x; echo "test\h\jtest"; set +x'
+ echo 'test\h\jtest'
test\h\jtest
```

From [POSIX Double quotes](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_03):

> The `<backslash>` shall retain its special meaning as an escape character (see Escape Character (Backslash)) only when followed by one of the following characters

**That's why** backslashes get removed inside quoted strings for:

```
$   `   "   \   <newline>
```

Example:

```
$ ksh -c 'set -x; echo "test\"\h\j\"test"; set +x'
+ echo 'test"\h\j"test'
test"\h\j"test
```

That is what happens when the first character found is a (double) quote.

When what is found is an initial backquote  (`` ` ``) the parsing rules are different. First, the string starts unquoted (internal double quotes may start a quoted section) and there is only **one** quoting scope (until the closing (`` ` ``). Note the single `"` on the first line below:

```
$ set -x; echo `echo \"\`echo \\"test\\" \`\"`; set +x
+++ echo '"test"'
++ echo '""test""'
+ echo '""test""'
""test""
+ set +x
```

A `$(…)`, instead, starts a **new** quoting scope every time.

```
$ set -x; echo $(echo \"$(echo \\"test\\" )\"); set +x
+++ echo '\test\'
++ echo '"\test\"'
+ echo '"\test\"'
"\test\"
+ set +x
```

The result is completely different.